# Uploading a file in cpanel

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress theme from scratch for my website and I am wondering, do I need to reupload the file everytime I change something?

Comment: Perhaps with quantum computing becoming more mainstream, we can get "spooky action at distance", where changes in files in my laptop automatically change the state of their entangled partners at my production server. _But only when I mentally observe said deployment_, because otherwise it'd be a mess. *Yes, you definitely need to have your changes present on the server if you want them to be live.*

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to keep in mind is that your WordPress site is displaying whatever content is on your remote server. If you're creating something locally (on your computer) you would need to upload it to that remote server to reflect changes.

Since you're using cPanel, it's cumbersome to continuously upload changed files into the server, so look at setting up an FTP connection with an app like FileZilla.